# Use Python format string in reverse for parsing

Tags: python

I've been using the following python code to format an integer part ID as a formatted part number string:

```
pn = 'PN-{:0>9}'.format(id)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to use that same format string (`'PN-{:0>9}'`) in reverse to extract the integer ID from the formatted part number. If that can't be done, is there a way to use a single format string (or regex?) to create and parse?

Comment: Don't use the name `id`. It is also the name of a built-in.

Comment: While the basic rule of avoiding builtin names is a good one, in practice, the `id` builtin is rarely used, and overriding it within the scope of a method is unlikely to raise any issues. This rule is more applicable when people name variables that override types, like `list`, `dict`, `set`, and `str`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The [parse module](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) "is the opposite of format()".

Example usage:

```
>>> import parse
>>> format_string = 'PN-{:0>9}'
>>> id = 123
>>> pn = format_string.format(id)
>>> pn
'PN-000000123'
>>> parsed = parse.parse(format_string, pn)
>>> parsed
<Result ('123',) {}>
>>> parsed[0]
'123'
```

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong, but what I get is `parsed[0]="000000123"` in python=3.6 and parse=1.12.1.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution in case you don't want to use the parse module. It converts format strings into regular expressions with named groups. It makes a few assumptions (described in the docstring) that were okay in my case, but may not be okay in yours.

```
def match_format_string(format_str, s):
    """Match s against the given format string, return dict of matches.

    We assume all of the arguments in format string are named keyword arguments (i.e. no {} or
    {:0.2f}). We also assume that all chars are allowed in each keyword argument, so separators
    need to be present which aren't present in the keyword arguments (i.e. '{one}{two}' won't work
    reliably as a format string but '{one}-{two}' will if the hyphen isn't used in {one} or {two}).

    We raise if the format string does not match s.

    Example:
    fs = '{test}-{flight}-{go}'
    s = fs.format('first', 'second', 'third')
    match_format_string(fs, s) -> {'test': 'first', 'flight': 'second', 'go': 'third'}
    """

    # First split on any keyword arguments, note that the names of keyword arguments will be in the
    # 1st, 3rd, ... positions in this list
    tokens = re.split(r'\{(.*?)\}', format_str)
    keywords = tokens[1::2]

    # Now replace keyword arguments with named groups matching them. We also escape between keyword
    # arguments so we support meta-characters there. Re-join tokens to form our regexp pattern
    tokens[1::2] = map(u'(?P<{}>.*)'.format, keywords)
    tokens[0::2] = map(re.escape, tokens[0::2])
    pattern = ''.join(tokens)

    # Use our pattern to match the given string, raise if it doesn't match
    matches = re.match(pattern, s)
    if not matches:
        raise Exception("Format string did not match")

    # Return a dict with all of our keywords and their values
    return {x: matches.group(x) for x in keywords}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
id = int(pn.split('-')[1])
```

This splits the part number at the dash, takes the second component and converts it to integer.

P.S. I've kept `id` as the variable name so that the connection to your question is clear. It is a good idea to rename that variable that it doesn't shadow [the built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).

Comment: +1 The question is kinda vague with no example but this works.

Comment: The question isn't vague at all, and this answer completely misses the point. The OP is looking for a single string that can be used in formatting to output his data in a particular form, and wants to use that same string as a regex to parse that same text back into an integer.

Comment: I found that i can get the ID number from the part number string with `id = int(re.search('(?<=PN-)\w+', pn).group(0))`, but can i use that regular expression to create a string from the ID?
(Go from 1234 to PN-000001234 then back to 1234)

Answer (score 0):

Use [lucidity](https://lucidity.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tutorial.html)

```
import lucidty

template = lucidity.Template('model', '/jobs/{job}/assets/{asset_name}/model/{lod}/{asset_name}_{lod}_v{version}.{filetype}')

path = '/jobs/monty/assets/circus/model/high/circus_high_v001.abc'
data = template.parse(path)
print(data)

# Output 
#   {'job': 'monty', 
#    'asset_name': 'circus',
#    'lod': 'high', 
#    'version': '001', 
#    'filetype': 'abc'}
```