# Convert, or unformat, a string to variables (like format(), but in reverse) in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have strings of the form `Version 1.4.0\n` and `Version 1.15.6\n`, and I'd like a simple way of extracting the three numbers from them.  I know I can put variables into a string with the format method; I basically want to do that backwards, like this:

```
# So I know I can do this:
x, y, z = 1, 4, 0
print 'Version {0}.{1}.{2}\n'.format(x,y,z)
# Output is 'Version 1.4.0\n'

# But I'd like to be able to reverse it:

mystr='Version 1.15.6\n'
a, b, c = mystr.unformat('Version {0}.{1}.{2}\n')

# And have the result that a, b, c = 1, 15, 6
```

Someone else I found asked the same question, but the reply was specific to their particular case:  [Use Python format string in reverse for parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663093/use-python-format-string-in-reverse-for-parsing)

A general answer (how to do `format()` in reverse) would be great!  An answer for my specific case would be very helpful too though.

Comment: i see some answers below that are direct for your problem. but a better solution would be to use regular expressions imho.

Comment: This seems a good use for [scanf](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502213-simple-scanf-implementation/) C-style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the Python regular expression library already provides the general functionality you are asking for. You just have to change the syntax of the pattern slightly

```
>>> import re
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> mystr='Version 1.15.6\n'
>>> m = re.match('Version (?P<_0>.+)\.(?P<_1>.+)\.(?P<_2>.+)', mystr)
>>> map(itemgetter(1), sorted(m.groupdict().items()))
['1', '15', '6']
```

As you can see, you have to change the (un)format strings from {0} to (?P<_0>.+). You could even require a decimal with (?P<_0>\d+). In addition, you have to escape some of the characters to prevent them from beeing interpreted as regex special characters. But this in turm can be automated again e.g. with

```
>>> re.sub(r'\\{(\d+)\\}', r'(?P<_\1>.+)', re.escape('Version {0}.{1}.{2}'))
'Version\\ (?P<_0>.+)\\.(?P<_1>.+)\\.(?P<_2>.+)'
```

Answer (score 11):

Just to build on [Uche's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11849360/698289), I was looking for a way to reverse a string via a  pattern with kwargs. So I put together the following function:

```
def string_to_dict(string, pattern):
    regex = re.sub(r'{(.+?)}', r'(?P<_\1>.+)', pattern)
    values = list(re.search(regex, string).groups())
    keys = re.findall(r'{(.+?)}', pattern)
    _dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
    return _dict
```

Which works as per:

```
>>> p = 'hello, my name is {name} and I am a {age} year old {what}'

>>> s = p.format(name='dan', age=33, what='developer')
>>> s
'hello, my name is dan and I am a 33 year old developer'
>>> string_to_dict(s, p)
{'age': '33', 'name': 'dan', 'what': 'developer'}

>>> s = p.format(name='cody', age=18, what='quarterback')
>>> s
'hello, my name is cody and I am a 18 year old quarterback'
>>> string_to_dict(s, p)
{'age': '18', 'name': 'cody', 'what': 'quarterback'}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, however it does't work if you have regex metacharacters in the input strings eg. `()`. Can you eventually update the answer to also handle this case? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', 'Version 1.15.6\n')
[('1', '15', '6')]
```

Comment: Oops, what I meant was `x,y,z = [int(num) for result in re.findall('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', 'Version 1.15.6\n') for num in result]`

Comment: a, b, c = re.findall('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', 'Version 1.15.6\n')[0]

Comment: That's a nice refinement but it still doesn't convert the results to integers. I amend my example: `x,y,z = [int(num) for num in re.findall('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', 'Version 1.15.6\n')[0]]`

Answer (score 8):

The pypi package `parse` serves this purpose well:

```
pip install parse
```

Can be used like this:

```
>>> import parse
>>> result=parse.parse('Version {0}.{1}.{2}\n', 'Version 1.15.6\n')
<Result ('1', '15', '6') {}>
>>> values=list(result)
>>> print(values)
['1', '15', '6']
```

Note that [the docs say](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) the `parse` package does not EXACTLY emulate the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) by default; it also uses some type-indicators specified by `re`. Of special note is that `s` means "whitespace" by default, rather than `str`. This can be easily modified to be consistent with the format specification by changing the default type for `s` to `str` (using `extra_types`):

```
result = parse.parse(format_str, string, extra_types=dict(s=str))
```

Here is a conceptual idea for a modification of the `string.Formatter` built-in class using the `parse` package to add `unformat` capability that I have used myself:

```
import parse
from string import Formatter
class Unformatter(Formatter):
    '''A parsable formatter.'''
    def unformat(self, format, string, extra_types=dict(s=str), evaluate_result=True):
        return parse.parse(format, string, extra_types, evaluate_result)
    unformat.__doc__ = parse.Parser.parse.__doc__
```

IMPORTANT: the method name `parse` is already in use by the `Formatter` class, so I have chosen `unformat` instead to avoid conflicts.

UPDATE: You might use it like this- very similar to the [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string.Formatter) class.

Formatting (identical to `'{:d} {:d}'.format(1, 2)`):

```
>>> formatter = Unformatter() 
>>> s = formatter.format('{:d} {:d}', 1, 2)
>>> s
'1 2'
```

Unformatting:

```
>>> result = formatter.unformat('{:d} {:d}', s)
>>> result
<Result (1, 2) {}>
>>> tuple(result)
(1, 2)
```

This is of course of very limited use as shown above. However, I've put up a pypi package ([parmatter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parmatter) - a project originally for my own use but maybe others will find it useful) that explores some ideas of how to put this idea to more useful work. The package relies heavily on the aforementioned [`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) package. EDIT: a few years of experience under my belt later, I realized `parmatter` (my first package!) was a terrible, embarrassing idea and have since deleted it.

Comment: How do I use this class you describe at the end?. Looks like a perfect addition to regular string methods.

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I made the code below that does the reverse of format but limited to the cases I needed.

**And**, I never tried it, but I think this is also the purpose of the [`parse library`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse)

My code:

```
import string
import re

_def_re   = '.+'
_int_re   = '[0-9]+'
_float_re = '[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?'

_spec_char = '[\^$.|?*+()'

def format_parse(text, pattern):
    """
    Scan `text` using the string.format-type `pattern`

    If `text` is not a string but iterable return a list of parsed elements

    All format-like pattern cannot be process:
      - variable name cannot repeat (even unspecified ones s.t. '{}_{0}')
      - alignment is not taken into account
      - only the following variable types are recognized:
           'd' look for and returns an integer
           'f' look for and returns a  float

    Examples::

        res = format_parse('the depth is -42.13', 'the {name} is {value:f}')
        print res
        print type(res['value'])
        # {'name': 'depth', 'value': -42.13}
        # <type 'float'>

        print 'the {name} is {value:f}'.format(**res)
        # 'the depth is -42.130000'

        # Ex2: without given variable name and and invalid item (2nd)
        versions = ['Version 1.4.0', 'Version 3,1,6', 'Version 0.1.0']
        v = format_parse(versions, 'Version {:d}.{:d}.{:d}')
        # v=[{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 0}, None, {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0}]

    """
    # convert pattern to suitable regular expression & variable name
    v_int = 0   # available integer variable name for unnamed variable 
    cur_g = 0   # indices of current regexp group name 
    n_map = {}  # map variable name (keys) to regexp group name (values)
    v_cvt = {}  # (optional) type conversion function attached to variable name
    rpattern = '^'    # stores to regexp pattern related to format pattern        

    for txt,vname, spec, conv in string.Formatter().parse(pattern):
        # process variable name
        if len(vname)==0:
            vname = v_int
            v_int += 1
        if vname not in n_map:
            gname = '_'+str(cur_g)
            n_map[vname] = gname
            cur_g += 1                   
        else:    
            gname = n_map[vname]

        # process type of required variables 
        if   'd' in spec: vtype = _int_re;   v_cvt[vname] = int
        elif 'f' in spec: vtype = _float_re; v_cvt[vname] = float
        else:             vtype = _def_re;

        # check for regexp special characters in txt (add '\' before)
        txt = ''.join(map(lambda c: '\\'+c if c in _spec_char else c, txt))

        rpattern += txt + '(?P<'+gname+'>' + vtype +')'

    rpattern += '$'

    # replace dictionary key from regexp group-name to the variable-name 
    def map_result(match):
        if match is None: return None
        match = match.groupdict()
        match = dict((vname, match[gname]) for vname,gname in n_map.iteritems())
        for vname, value in match.iteritems():
            if vname in v_cvt:
                match[vname] = v_cvt[vname](value)
        return match

    # parse pattern
    if isinstance(text,basestring):
        match = re.search(rpattern, text)
        match = map_result(match)
    else:
        comp  = re.compile(rpattern)
        match = map(comp.search, text)
        match = map(map_result, match)

    return match
```

for your case, here is a use example:

```
versions = ['Version 1.4.0', 'Version 3.1.6', 'Version 0.1.0']
v = format_parse(versions, 'Version {:d}.{:d}.{:d}')
# v=[{0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 0}, {0: 3, 1: 1, 2: 6}, {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0}]

# to get the versions as a list of integer list, you can use:
v = [[vi[i] for i in range(3)] for vi in filter(None,v)]
```

Note the `filter(None,v)` to remove unparsable versions (which return None). Here it is not necessary.

Comment: Surprisingly this worked a lot better the `parse` library. To make this work with python3, just change `basestring` to `str` and `dict.iteritems()` to `dict.items()`

Answer (score 2):

This

```
a, b, c = (int(i) for i in mystr.split()[1].split('.'))
```

will give you `int` values for `a`, `b` and `c`

```
>>> a
1
>>> b
15
>>> c
6
```

Depending on how regular or irregular, i.e., consistent, your number/version formats will be, you may want to consider the use of *regular expressions*, though if they will stay in this format, I would favor the simpler solution if it works for you.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, you are right .. I learned about list comprehension first, so that's where I go initially, but you are right, there's no need to keep a list - thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: Using a generator in this case makes no sense, list comprehension will do the job fine.

Comment: @Willian I don't understand, how would you write a compact loop to convert the list of characters to ints? (which was the reason)

Comment: like [int(i) for i in mystr.split()[1].split('.')], as your initial answer was

Comment: @Willian You mean list comprehension? Yes, I had that originally,  but we are not interested in keeping a list, so using a generator makes this more explicit. (for something this short it really doesn't make a difference of you use LC or a generator, both will work, but it is semantically more clear)

Comment: @Willian What is the drawback you see? Not arguing, just curious

Comment: @Levon I can't see any big drawback, I was responding to ashwini that using a generator would be beter, but a LC will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in case you don't want to use the parse module. It converts format strings into regular expressions with named groups. It makes a few assumptions (described in the docstring) that were okay in my case, but may not be okay in yours.

```
def match_format_string(format_str, s):
    """Match s against the given format string, return dict of matches.

    We assume all of the arguments in format string are named keyword arguments (i.e. no {} or
    {:0.2f}). We also assume that all chars are allowed in each keyword argument, so separators
    need to be present which aren't present in the keyword arguments (i.e. '{one}{two}' won't work
    reliably as a format string but '{one}-{two}' will if the hyphen isn't used in {one} or {two}).

    We raise if the format string does not match s.

    Example:
    fs = '{test}-{flight}-{go}'
    s = fs.format('first', 'second', 'third')
    match_format_string(fs, s) -> {'test': 'first', 'flight': 'second', 'go': 'third'}
    """

    # First split on any keyword arguments, note that the names of keyword arguments will be in the
    # 1st, 3rd, ... positions in this list
    tokens = re.split(r'\{(.*?)\}', format_str)
    keywords = tokens[1::2]

    # Now replace keyword arguments with named groups matching them. We also escape between keyword
    # arguments so we support meta-characters there. Re-join tokens to form our regexp pattern
    tokens[1::2] = map(u'(?P<{}>.*)'.format, keywords)
    tokens[0::2] = map(re.escape, tokens[0::2])
    pattern = ''.join(tokens)

    # Use our pattern to match the given string, raise if it doesn't match
    matches = re.match(pattern, s)
    if not matches:
        raise Exception("Format string did not match")

    # Return a dict with all of our keywords and their values
    return {x: matches.group(x) for x in keywords}
```