# How do I alphabetize data in a txt file to a list

Tags: python

txt file

```
Zurich, Sun, (8, 52)
Auckland, Sun, (20, 52)
Barcelona, Sun, (8, 52)
Vancouver, Sun, (0, 52)
Beirut, Sun, (9, 52)
Athens, Sun, (9, 52)
Amsterdam, Sun, (8, 520)
Toronto, Sun, (2, 52)
Vienna, Sun, (8, 52)
Winnipeg, Sun, (1, 52)
Atlanta, Sun, (2, 52)
Anchorage, Sat, (23, 52)
Warsaw, Sun, (8, 52)
Ankara, Sun, (10, 52)
Washington DC, Sun, (2, 52)
```

code:

```
list_aldskjfa = []
data = open('city_time.txt', 'r')
data = data.read()
list1 = []
for line in sorted(open('A1_cities_and_time.txt')):
    list1.append(line)
    print(line, end='')
print(list1)
```

```
output: ['Amsterdam, Sun, (8, 520)\n', 'Anchorage, Sat, (23, 52)\n', 'Ankara, Sun, (10, 52)\n', 'Athens, Sun, (9, 52)\n', 'Atlanta, Sun, (2, 52)\n', 'Auckland, Sun, (20, 52)\n', 'Barcelona, Sun, (8, 52)\n', 'Beirut, Sun, (9, 52)\n', 'Toronto, Sun, (2, 52)\n', 'Vancouver, Sun, (0, 52)\n', 'Vienna, Sun, (8, 52)\n', 'Warsaw, Sun, (8, 52)\n', 'Washington DC, Sun, (2, 52)', 'Winnipeg, Sun, (1, 52)\n', 'Zurich, Sun, (8, 52)\n']
```

As you can see, the list is alphabetized properly, with amsterdam, then anchorage, then ankara, etc. The problem is that the entire thing is a string - including the tuple and the date. The ideal output would look like [('Amsterdam', 'Sun', (8,520)), ('Anchorage', 'Sun', (8,520)), etc.]

Comment: Take a look at this library https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html you will be able to read it in more easely and then convert the strings to the appropriate types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though what you need to do is split each entry of the list into a tuple. One nice solution is to use the [parse module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18620969/2476977). Here's a way to do it from scratch.

```
def sep(line):
    line = line.strip()
    parts = line.split(', ',maxsplit = 2)
    return tuple(parts[:2] + [eval(parts[2])])

output = list(map(sep,list1))
```

To include the the file reading in the code, we could proceed as follows.

```
def sep(line):
    line = line.strip()
    parts = line.split(', ',maxsplit = 2)
    return tuple(parts[:2] + [eval(parts[2])])

with open('list.txt','r') as f:
    output = list(map(sep,f.readlines()))
output.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this solution assumes you convert the text file to a csv (just rename the ending). Here is an alternative implementation to get the last element as a tuple:

```
import csv, ast

output = []
with open('path/to/city_time.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            row = row[:2] + [",".join(row[2:])]
            output.append(row)


output = sorted(output)

for o in output:
    o[2] = ast.literal_eval(o[2].strip())

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['Amsterdam', ' Sun', (8, 520)], ['Anchorage', ' Sat', (23, 52)], ['Ankara', ' Sun', (10, 52)], ['Athens', ' Sun', (9, 52)], ['Atlanta', ' Sun', (2, 52)], ['Auckland', ' Sun', (20, 52)], ['Barcelona', ' Sun', (8, 52)], ['Beirut', ' Sun', (9, 52)], ['Toronto', ' Sun', (2, 52)], ['Vancouver', ' Sun', (0, 52)], ['Vienna', ' Sun', (8, 52)], ['Warsaw', ' Sun', (8, 52)], ['Washington DC', ' Sun', (2, 52)], ['Winnipeg', ' Sun', (1, 52)], ['Zurich', ' Sun', (8, 52)]]
```